# How to correctly handle PHP DateTime Object issue when moving between years

Tags: php, date

I'm currently trying to do a small calendar.

On the click of my button, I call an AJAX function that will return data from my db and send it into my custom calendar (full html).

I've set the first month to November.

How do I handle the year when moving from December 2018 to January 2019 ?

I have this :

```
$newBeginDate = new DateTime($dateBegin, $timeZoneParis);
$lastDayThisMonth = new DateTime($newBeginDate->format('Y-m-t'));

$newBeginDate->modify('+1 month');
```

I have the right month, until  I try to go to January (nothing happened (I'm stuck with December 2018, can't go to January 2019), I don't see the way to do this).

Comment: What do you mean, *nothing happened*? Your code does not do anything except setting and modifying variables. Post your real code, what happens and what should happen.

Comment: I know nothing happened because I didn't wrote the code yet, but I'm stuck, I . don't see what to do (that's why I'm asking for help)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newBeginDate->format('Y-m-t')
```

`t` is *Number of days in the given month* not *Day of the month*.

Try instead:

```
$newBeginDate->format('Y-m-d')
```

Edit: I understand you might be using that as you’re only using this function to get the month, but if you go from January to February, you’ll either have an error, or you’ll end up at the start of March.

Comment: Considering that the name of the variable is `$lastDayThisMonth`, the `t` option would seem exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @jeroen very true, but OP is also not even using `$lastDayThisMonth` so it’s hard to understand the context. My answer is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Here's my PHP code :

```
                $dateBegin =  $currentYearPost. "-".$currentMonthPost."-01";
                $dateEnd = $currentYearPost . "-".$currentMonthPost."-t";

                $newBeginDate = new DateTime($dateBegin, $timeZoneParis);
                if($_POST['next'] != ""){
                    $newBeginDate->modify('+1 month');
                }else{
                    $newBeginDate->modify('-1 month');
                }
                $period = new DatePeriod($newBeginDate,new DateInterval('P1D'),$lastDayThisMonth);
```

Nothing happened because I was using jQuery the wrong way :

> $('#nextMonth, #previousMonth').on('click', function(){

To outside the $(document).ready

> $('#nextMonth, #previousMonth').live('click', function(){